# error with function returning a structure

Tags: c, struct, structure

This is what I am trying to do:

I have been working on code that I have create a structure (hard coded in main) Then I want to malloc space for two structs (tryin to use functions). Then copy all the data in the first struct to the second struct and print the new structure.

The errors the occur is:
I don't understand what this error means.

```
pointer.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
pointer.c:13: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pointer.h"
int rec = 0;
```

line 7

```
struct emp *create(int record){
emp *new_employees = malloc(sizeof(info) * (record+1));

return new_employees;   
}
```

line 13

```
struct emp *copy(emp *data, int record){
emp *new_employee = create(record+1);
int i;
for(i = 0; i<record;i++){
    new_employee.first = data.first;
    new_employee.last = data.last;
    new_employee.start_date = data.start_date;
    new_employess.sal = data.sal;
    data++;
}
return new_employee;
}


int main(void){
struct info employees;
employees.first = "FIRST";
employees.last = "LAST";
employees.start_date = "June-20th-2006";
employees.sal = 55555.55;
rec = rec+1;



}
```

header file:

```
#include <string.h>
struct info {
char *first;
char *last;
char *start_date;
float sal;
} emp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info` is not a type, and `emp` is just a variable of type `struct info`. Either add a typedef (if you want to `emp` as a type):

```
typedef struct info {
    char *first;
    char *last;
    char *start_date;
    float sal;
} emp;
```

...or add a `struct` keyword.

```
struct info *create(int record);
struct info *copy(emp *data, int record);
```

Comment: Yes, but `info` is the type, not `emp`

Comment: @LudovicKuty Yeah, confused it. I updated the answer but it won't show as edited…

Answer (score 0):

`emp` is a variable, `info` is the type. So you should use `info` instead of `emp` in the prototype of your function and the body too.

Like others said, a `typedef` is missing or a `struct info` instead of `emp`. I missed that one :)

IMHO those are two distinct errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
emp *new_employees = malloc(sizeof(info) * (record+1));
```

The name of the type is `struct info`, not `info`.

But a better way to write that is:

emp *new_employees = malloc((record+1) * sizeof *emp);

Comment: The other post are say that if do what you have posted I should 

    struct info *new_employees = malloc(sizeof(info) * (record+1));

Comment: @jenglee: `sizeof(info)` will work only if you've declared `info` as a typedef.  You can do that if you like, or you can just refer to the type by its original name, `struct info`.  But `sizeof *emp` is more robust; it doesn't risk accidentally using the wrong type name, and doesn't need to be changed if you later change the type of `emp`.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the functions like this:

```
struct emp *create()
struct emp *copy()
```

Or define the structures as a data type using typedef.

Comment: Are you saying I should define this in the header file

Comment: When you define the functions. They must return a _struct emp_ instead of _emp_